# DelegateCommand in Prism whose canExecuteMethod is determined by a property in an ObservableCollection. How do I continue to "Observe" canExecute?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I have an observable collection of a class that implements both `BindableBase` and `IDataErrorInfo`. In my view, I have a button whose `ICommand` binding should only be executable when each element in the observable collection is validated. Since one of the elements is almost always going to start out invalid, the button is originally disabled. I have the following code in my constructor:

```
this.StartInspectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.StartInspection, () => this.Parameters.All(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p["Value"])))
```

Where my observable collection is defined as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
```

And the implementation of `IDataErrorInfo` in my Paramters class is like this:

```
public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName != "Value" // Only validate value column
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._validationExpression) // No validation means all values including null are valid
                || (this.Value != null && Regex.IsMatch(this.Value, this._validationExpression))) // No null allowed when validating
            {
                return "";  // No error
            }

            return this._validationMessage;
        }
    }
```

What is the syntax for getting the canExecuteMethod to be re-evaluated when the user enters valid values into the various Parameters? (Or, for that matter, causes currently valid ones to invalidate.)

I understand how to use `ObservesCanExecute` and `ObservesProperty<T>` for properties themselves, but I'm not sure how to apply that to a property inside of a class that's part of the `ObservableCollection`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Brian Lagunas' answer you could handle the `PropertyChanged` event for all items in your `Parameters` collection and call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method whenever any item's property is changed, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.StartInspectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.StartInspection, () => this.Parameters.All(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p["Value"])))
        this.Parameters.CollectionChanged += Parameters_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();

    private void Parameters_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object parameter in e.NewItems)
            {
                (parameter as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object parameter in e.OldItems)
            {
                (parameter as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartInspectionCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method worked perfectly. (I used a lambda PropertyChangedEventHandler expression instead of a method, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the ObservesProperty or ObservesCanExcute in this scenario.  You have to manually call StartInspectionCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged when properties in your collection have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any gravediggers still looking for answers to this question I have found a different workaround for this problem as I could not get my ObservableCollection to fire the CollectionChanged event.

After populating the collection I manually iterated and set the propertychanged for each item, as below:

```
OrdersToConfirm = new ObservableCollection<mConfirmedQuote>(_quoteService.GetOrdersToBeConfirmed());
OrdersToConfirm.ToList().ForEach(x => { x.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged; });

private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     ConfirmCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

I am not sure what the drawbacks are of doing it this way, if any but will update if I run into any.